# How to debug MonoTouch app on simulator?

Tags: debugging, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm testing MonoTouch (the idea of developing in C# rather than objective-C sounds great). I wrote a very simple app, that compiles well, and runs nicely on the simulator.

But whenever I add breakpoints and hit Debug, I get:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Address already in use
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind (System.Net.EndPoint local_end) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Debugger.Soft.VirtualMachineManager.BeginListen (System.Net.IPEndPoint dbg_ep, System.Net.IPEndPoint con_ep, System.AsyncCallback callback) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft.RemoteSoftDebuggerSession.StartListening (MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft.RemoteDebuggerStartInfo dsi) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft.IPhone.IPhoneDebuggerSession.OnRun (Mono.Debugging.Client.DebuggerStartInfo startInfo) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Debugging.Client.DebuggerSession+<Run>c__AnonStorey6.<>m__2 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I've tried reading the documentation and FAQs, changing targets, and almost every other solution I could google (most weren't relevant - it seems this error mostly crops up when you develop ASP.Net Mono projects). I'm really hoping there's a simple"turn that switch" solution to this.

For the record, I'm using:

1. MonoDevelop 2.4.2
2. MonoFramework-2.10.1_3
3. MonoTouch 4 Trial (could that be blocking debugging?)
4. Mac O X 10.6.7
5. Libraries added: System.Net, System.Text, System.IO and reference to System.Json

As always, thanks for your time,

Guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like some other process is using the same port that the soft debugger is trying to use.

Try this command in terminal:

```
sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"
```

It should help you figure out what process is causing the issue.  Hopefully it is something you can close/kill or remove from your Mac.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! Got me on the right track. Apparently the debugger is using port 10000 (need to find out how to change that), which was used by another application on my machine. I managed to start the debugger, but it quits within a minute. Will do some more research, although I'm not really sure what stops it - this answered the main question.

Comment: Actually, I found out that I can't use breakpoints to debug the startup process of the app (as explained here: http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Debugging) so the solution is 100% accepted.